# How can we force browsers/ravenjs to report errors in English?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, sentry, raven

Recently we opened up sentry in a way to capture JS errors. The problem we noticed is that a lot of errors came back in other languages. We threw the error messages into google translate they looked eerily similar to some equivalent errors in English. We then realized the browser errors occur in the user's browser language.

Is there a way we can force the errors to be in English?

Comment: I'm pretty sure we don't have enough information to help you solve this.

Comment: I'm unsure about what other information would be helpful. The users have browsers in different locales, when we get error reports they are localized. Does the browser have anything to request an English version of the error? Can you ask some questions so I can give you more helpful information?

Comment: Parris is specifically asking about localized errors in JavaScript. i.e. if your browsers locale is in German, the error message may be in German.

I'm not actually sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do this today is with a centralized database that would convert them. It's something that's not super practical, and unfortunately this feature (localized errors) was created at a time when the browser was used for different things.